# iOS Upload file to Amazon S3 with pre-signed link(From Backend) But after Downloading File is getting corrupt

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, amazon-s3, data-structures

**Below is my code for uploading its give success response and file is getting upload also but when we download after download it's showing file is corrupt**

**I am using Alamofire for Upload**

```
func uploadMultiPartData(data: Data?  , inURL : String? , parameters : [String : Any] , file_name : NSString , onCompletion: @escaping ServiceResponse){
        var url : String!
        url = inURL
        var header : [String : String]?
        header = ["contentType" : "\(file_name.deletingPathExtension)/\(file_name.pathExtension)"]


    let URL = try! URLRequest(url: url!, method: .put, headers: header)

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                if let vl = value as? String {
                    multipartFormData.append(vl.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                } else if let vl = value as? Int {
                    multipartFormData.append(String(vl).data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
            }

            if let data = parameters["data"] as? Data {
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: file_name as String )
            }



        },  with: URL, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
            switch result{

            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseString { response in
                   (response.response?.allHeaderFields)!)

                    var dataSource : AnyObject?

                    if response.error != nil{
                        return
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Please help me out for this

Comment: What's your filename? Did you re-check your content-Type in header

Comment: Yes its fine i think  (ContentType : mimeType)
Do i need to pass some more parameter in Header.

Comment: "Corrupt" can be a lot of things.  Verify the basics: examine the object in the bucket, using the console.  Is it the correct number of bytes? If not, stop there, download it, and examine it with a hex editor. Compare to the original.

Comment: Why not use the iOS AWS framework?